# t-test as Mahalanobis distance

Tags: t-test, distance

Our tutor once said that the *t*-test applies Mahalanobis distance. Could you please explain how it does so?

Comment: I think a good answer to this question would also mention [Hotelling's *T*-squared distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution), which in a sense generalises Student's *t* to multiple dimensions, which is the situation one normally encounters Mahalanobis distances. The relationship between the one-dimensional case and the univariate Student's *t* is pretty clear once we see them both as measuring "standard deviations from the mean".

Comment: (That is very much a comment not an answer though - there's some subtleties about standard deviation *of what*? There is a link to PCA too - quick search for T squared, Mahalanobis and PCA produces some results which are at least tangentially relevant to the OP.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will only discuss the (independent) two-sample case:

Let $x,y$ be observations (matrices) from two $p$-dim multivariate distributions. Then the Mahalanobis distance is given by 
$$
   D_M^2 = (\bar{x}-\bar{y})^T S^{-1} (\bar{x}-\bar{y})
$$
where $S$ is the sample covariance matrix. In the scalar case the $t$-statistic is given by $t^2 \propto \frac{(\bar{x}-\bar{y})^2}{\hat{\sigma}^2}$ which is (up to the scale factor I omitted) the same as the Mahalanobis distance for $S=(\hat{\sigma}^2)$.

The multivariate generalization of the $t$-statistic is the Hotelling $T$-squared given by
$$
   T^2 = \frac{n_x n_y}{n_x+n_y}(\bar{x}-\bar{y})^T S^{-1} (\bar{x}-\bar{y})
$$
which is proportional to the Mahalonibis distance. For more information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance  and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution.